# How to Set up curl with Bash Script to download a file

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to set up a Bash Script (shl) that will use curl to download a file.
I really can't find a good bash script tutorial.  I need assistance.

I've tried testing it with a windows bat file that has something like 
: `curl ${url} > file name`   [trying to see it work from windows]

and getting
 Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

the URL that I can use to extract the file would look something like this {example only)

https://bigstate.academicworks.com/api/v1/disbursements.csv?per_page=3&fields=id,disbursement_amount,portfolio_name,user_uid,user_display_name,portfolio_code,category_name&token=fcc28431bcb6771437861378aefe4a4474dbf9e503c78fd9a4db05924600c03b

I'm trying to put the file here `\aiken\ProdITFileTrans\cofc_aw_disbursement.csv`

so my bat file looks

```
@Echo On
curl --verbose -g ${https://bigstate.academicworks.com/api/v1/disbursements.csv?per_page=3&fields=id,disbursement_amount,portfolio_name,user_uid,user_display_name,portfolio_code,category_name&token=fcc28431bcb6771437861378aefe4a4474dbf9e503c78fd9a4db05924600c03b} >\\aiken\ProdITFileTrans\cofc_aw_disbursement.csv
PAUSE
```

Again the goal is to take a working version of this call in put in in a Bash shell that I can call forom ATOMIC/UC4

Once I have the bash script I want to be able to do a daily download of my file.

Comment: I think you're mixing up Bash scripts and batch files, which is it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, perhaps something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl --verbose -g yourlongurlhere -o /path/to/your/file.csv
```

Make the file executable (`chmod +x`).

EDIT: check [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) for tons of examples. It covers just about everything.

Comment: and see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html for the daily execution part.